# Firestore: REST API call to runQueries

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

URL:[https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/{parent=projects/*/databases/*/documents}:runQuery](https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/%7Bparent=projects/*/databases/*/documents%7D:runQuery)

Request body:

```
{ structuredQuery: 
            { from: [
                { collectionId: 'questions' 
            }
        ], 
        orderBy: [
            { field: 
                { fieldPath: 'created' 
            }, direction: 'DESCENDING' }
        ], select: { fields: 
            [
                { fieldPath: 'id' }, 
                { fieldPath: 'details' }, 
                { fieldPath: 'question' }, 
                { fieldPath: 'votes' }
            ] 
        }, 
        where: { 
            compositeFilter: { 
                filters: [
                    { fieldFilter: { 
                        field: { 
                            fieldPath: 'author' 
                        }, 
                            op: 'EQUAL', 
                            value: { 
                                stringValue: "henry" 
                            } 
                        } 
                    }
                ], op: 'AND' 
            } 
        }, 
            limit: 4 
            } 
        }
```

**What error do I get?**

```
[{
    "readTime": "2022-12-26T12:46:55.107240Z"
}]
```

*the response isn't returning the expected results*

**What am I trying to do?**

1. Fetch the given field from the collection: "questions" where the "author" matches "henry"

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide more complete information about what isn't working the way you expect.  Are you getting an error?  Are you getting some query results that are unexpected?  Please edit the question to include enough detail that anyone can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Doug I just used the code segment as a reference (i took it from another answer). I have 0 idea about how i should structure the query. So i was hoping a code segment from a similiar question would serve as a template for volunteers to easily edit.

Comment: Welcome to SO! A couple of things about asking questions that will help us to help you. First, please don't use links in questions; if the link breaks (which they can do) it will make the question useless to future readers. Include a sample structure in the question - either as am image or text (text preferred). Secondly we don't know your structure! Include it (as just mentioned) as text in the question so we know what we have to work with. Lastly, Firestore doesn't have a  'closest match' query per se so we really need to understand what that means. Update the question and we'll take a look!

Comment: Okay. I'm pretty new. Thanks for the tips. I have updated the question

Comment: @Jay and as mentioned in the question, i don't have enpugh reps to attach an image. Text is not feasible either, as my image is essentially a screenshot of my firestore query builder that shows what exactly I'm trying to do

Comment: Why do you say that the linked documentation is outdated? If you have a specific problem with the docs, contact Firebase support directly with the observations you have that it doesn't work the way you expect.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for your response. As a beginner, some parts of the documentation feels pretty vague to me. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/runQuery. This is the documentation for what I'm trying to implement. I just don't understand how the request body should be structured. Hence this question

Comment: Unless I'm misinterpreting your question, you already have a request body.  Have you tried it? Does it not work the way you expect? This is what I was trying to get at in my very first comment.

Comment: Here's why we're asking for more specific data. First, one of the links in the question is dead so we don't know what that is. Second, the image of the query in the question shows a collection called `/testusers` but the code in your question shows `"from": [{"collectionId": "users"}]` which are different. If you update the code to use `testusers` does it work? Or is that not the name of the collection?

Comment: @DougStevenson The request body in the question is supposed to serve as a template. I have none - very little knowledge on how to use it. I just copied it from a different answer with a similiar question hoping that you guys can help me edit it to my own needs

Comment: @Jay The request body in the question is supposed to serve as a template. I have none - very little knowledge on how to use it. I just copied it from a different answer with a similiar question hoping that you guys can help me edit it to my own needs

Comment: Perhaps the easiest path forward is to actually try to use the template, experiment with it, and see how it works. Then, if it's not working the way you expect, post the actual code that you used so we can see if you did something wrong.  The lack of example code is the reason why this question was closed as "off-topic".

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api) is available and it looks pretty straighforward.

> #### Making REST calls
>
> All REST API endpoints exist under the base URL `https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/`.
>
> To create a path to a document with the ID `LA` in the collection
> `cities` under the project `YOUR_PROJECT_ID` you would use the
> following structure.
>
> ```
> /projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/cities/LA
> ```
>
> To interact with this path, combine it with the base API URL.
>
> ```
> https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/cities/LA
> ```
>
> The best way to begin experimenting with the REST API is to use
> the API Explorer, which automatically generates Google Identity OAuth
> 2.0 tokens and allows you to examine the API.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. As a beginner, some parts of the documentation feels pretty vague to me. One such part is running queries with REST API. Here is the doc link for what I'm trying to do: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/runQuery.

Comment: The OP is asking for how you would do a `FILTERED` GET request to the firestore ("where author matches Herny"), which is not specified in the documentation. This does not answer the OPs question.

Comment: Any news here? I'm stuck with the same "readTime" only response both in API explorer and in actual API call.